# Photoshop's save for web and devices incorrect file information

Tags: css, image, photoshop

I have a problem with "Save for web and devices" option in Photoshop. No matter what file type I choose, the output file information is always GIF. And I got the "future" size of GIF only. For example I want to save it as PNG24, but it show's me GIF ... the GIF size, and there is no transparency in the picture window ... same with JPEG and all another.

What should I do ... I tried to enter in every options I got, but I didn't find a solution?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of this window as you are saving?  Think I knew what the problem is.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Photoshop and/or your computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution. May be the only one option that I haven't been trying. When I choose the file format ... in the upper select menu - `"preset"` I haven't specified the exact value. I did it for every file type and it worked.